# How to convert a html page to a complete Vue or React project?

Tags: html, reactjs, vue.js, dashboard, adminlte

I am currently working on a dashboard based on AdminLTE 3. I removed the parts that I don't need and made some changes on the AdminLTE HTML and CSS files. The thing is I need this project to be a Vue or a React project. For now I only need the index.html (an empty dashboard, navbar, sidebar and a footer). There is one main CSS file which has all the classes that the project uses and there are some js files.

I tried to create an empty Vue project and create components like Navbar.vue, Footer.vue, Sidebar.vue etc. But I don't know how to integrate this one big CSS file for all of these and Js files as well. What should I do? I know there is no way to put all the script tags and links inside every components, that didn't work. Also I couldn't manage to use these files on the App.vue

Is there any way that I can convert this HTML project into a Vue or a React one?

Answer (score 1):

Vue is incrementally adoptable. And very small.
Which means you can use it to render just one button. Or you can render the entire contents of your page with it. Your choice.

Also, you can just take the existing HTML and place it inside the template of a `.vue` single file component (SFC). It doesn't even need a `<script>` tag.

Example:

```js
Vue.component('your-question', {
  template: `
  <div class="post-layout">
    <div class="votecell post-layout--left">
      <div class="js-voting-container grid fd-column ai-stretch gs4 fc-black-200" data-post-id="64535387">
        <button class="js-vote-up-btn grid--cell s-btn s-btn__unset c-pointer fc-theme-primary" data-controller="s-tooltip" data-s-tooltip-placement="right" aria-pressed="false" aria-label="Up vote" data-selected-classes="fc-theme-primary" aria-describedby="--stacks-s-tooltip-9i3a4gec"><svg aria-hidden="true" class="m0 svg-icon iconArrowUpLg" width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 36 36"><path d="M2 26h32L18 10 2 26z"></path></svg></button><div id="--stacks-s-tooltip-9i3a4gec" class="s-popover s-popover__tooltip pe-none" aria-hidden="true" role="tooltip">This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear<div class="s-popover--arrow"></div></div>
        <div class="js-vote-count grid--cell fc-black-500 fs-title grid fd-column ai-center c-pointer" itemprop="upvoteCount" data-value="1" role="button" tabindex="0" data-s-tooltip-placement="right" data-controller="null s-tooltip" aria-describedby="--stacks-s-tooltip-lk3p5mtq">0</div><div id="--stacks-s-tooltip-lk3p5mtq" class="s-popover s-popover__tooltip pe-none" aria-hidden="true" role="tooltip">View upvote and downvote totals.<div class="s-popover--arrow"></div></div>
        <button class="js-vote-down-btn grid--cell s-btn s-btn__unset c-pointer" data-controller="s-tooltip" data-s-tooltip-placement="right" aria-pressed="true" aria-label="Down vote" data-selected-classes="fc-theme-primary" aria-describedby="--stacks-s-tooltip-ib7zwamw"><svg aria-hidden="true" class="m0 svg-icon iconArrowDownLg" width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 36 36"><path d="M2 10h32L18 26 2 10z"></path></svg></button><div id="--stacks-s-tooltip-ib7zwamw" class="s-popover s-popover__tooltip pe-none wmx2" aria-hidden="true" role="tooltip" style="margin: 0px;">This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful (click again to undo)<div class="s-popover--arrow" style=""></div></div>
        <button class="js-bookmark-btn s-btn s-btn__unset c-pointer py4 js-gps-track" data-controller="s-tooltip" data-s-tooltip-placement="right" aria-pressed="false" aria-label="Bookmark" data-selected-classes="fc-yellow-600" data-gps-track="post.click({ item: 1, priv: 17, post_type: 1 })" aria-describedby="--stacks-s-tooltip-jn0zc88f">
          <svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-icon iconBookmark" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18"><path d="M6 1a2 2 0 00-2 2v14l5-4 5 4V3a2 2 0 00-2-2H6zm3.9 3.83h2.9l-2.35 1.7.9 2.77L9 7.59l-2.35 1.7.9-2.76-2.35-1.7h2.9L9 2.06l.9 2.77z"></path></svg>
          <div class="js-bookmark-count mt4 d-none" data-value=""></div>
        </button><div id="--stacks-s-tooltip-jn0zc88f" class="s-popover s-popover__tooltip pe-none" aria-hidden="true" role="tooltip">Bookmark this question.<div class="s-popover--arrow"></div></div>
        <a class="js-post-issue grid--cell s-btn s-btn__unset c-pointer py6 mx-auto" href="/posts/64535387/timeline" data-shortcut="T" data-controller="s-tooltip" data-s-tooltip-placement="right" aria-label="Timeline" aria-describedby="--stacks-s-tooltip-ud2iy1dm"><svg aria-hidden="true" class="mln2 mr0 svg-icon iconHistory" width="19" height="18" viewBox="0 0 19 18"><path d="M3 9a8 8 0 113.73 6.77L8.2 14.3A6 6 0 105 9l3.01-.01-4 4-4-4h3L3 9zm7-4h1.01L11 9.36l3.22 2.1-.6.93L10 10V5z"></path></svg></a><div id="--stacks-s-tooltip-ud2iy1dm" class="s-popover s-popover__tooltip pe-none" aria-hidden="true" role="tooltip">Show activity on this post.<div class="s-popover--arrow"></div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="postcell post-layout--right">
      <div class="s-prose js-post-body" itemprop="text">
        <p>I am currently working on a dashboard based on AdminLTE 3. I removed the parts that I don't need and made some changes on the AdminLTE HTML and CSS files. The thing is I need this project to be a Vue or a React project. For now I only need the index.html (an empty dashboard, navbar, sidebar and a footer). There is one main CSS file which has all the classes that the project uses and there are some js files.</p>
        <p>I tried to create an empty Vue project and create components like Navbar.vue, Footer.vue, Sidebar.vue etc. But I don't know how to integrate this one big CSS file for all of these and Js files as well. What should I do? I know there is no way to put all the script tags and links inside every components, that didn't work. Also I couldn't manage to use these files on the App.vue</p>
        <p>Is there any way that I can convert this HTML project into a Vue or a React one?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="mt24 mb12">
        <div class="post-taglist grid gs4 gsy fd-column">
          <div class="grid ps-relative">
            <span class="edit-tags-wrapper"><a href="/questions/tagged/html" class="post-tag js-gps-track" title="show questions tagged 'html'" rel="tag">html</a><a href="/questions/tagged/reactjs" class="post-tag js-gps-track" title="show questions tagged 'reactjs'" rel="tag">reactjs</a><a href="/questions/tagged/vue.js" class="post-tag js-gps-track" title="show questions tagged 'vue.js'" rel="tag">vue.js</a><a href="/questions/tagged/dashboard" class="post-tag js-gps-track" title="" rel="tag">dashboard</a><a href="/questions/tagged/adminlte" class="post-tag js-gps-track" title="show questions tagged 'adminlte'" rel="tag">adminlte</a><span><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="edit-tags" class="fw-normal p4 m2 ws-nowrap" title="Edit this question's tags">Edit tags</a></span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mb0 ">
        <div class="mt16 grid gs8 gsy fw-wrap jc-end ai-start pt4">
          <div class="grid--cell mr16" style="flex: 1 1 100px;">
            <div class="post-menu">
              <a href="/q/64535387/1891677" rel="nofollow" itemprop="url" class="js-share-link js-gps-track" title="short permalink to this question" data-gps-track="post.click({ item: 2, priv: 17, post_type: 1 })" data-controller="se-share-sheet s-popover" data-se-share-sheet-title="Share a link to this question" data-se-share-sheet-subtitle="(includes your user id)" data-se-share-sheet-post-type="question" data-se-share-sheet-social="facebook twitter devto" data-se-share-sheet-location="1" data-se-share-sheet-license-url="https%3a%2f%2fcreativecommons.org%2flicenses%2fby-sa%2f4.0%2f" data-se-share-sheet-license-name="CC BY-SA 4.0" data-s-popover-placement="bottom-start" aria-controls="se-share-sheet-0" data-action=" s-popover#toggle se-share-sheet#preventNavigation s-popover:show->se-share-sheet#willShow s-popover:shown->se-share-sheet#didShow">share</a><div class="s-popover z-dropdown" style="width: unset; max-width: 28em;" id="se-share-sheet-0"><div class="s-popover--arrow"></div><div><span class="js-title fw-bold">Share a link to this question</span> <span class="js-subtitle">(includes your user id)</span></div><div class="my8"><input type="text" class="js-input s-input wmn3 sm:wmn-initial" readonly=""></div><div class="d-flex jc-space-between mbn4"><button class="js-copy-link-btn s-btn s-btn__link">Copy link</button><a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/" rel="license" class="s-block-link fc-blue-600 js-license" target="_blank" title="The current license for this post: CC BY-SA 4.0">CC BY-SA 4.0</a><div class="js-social-container"></div></div></div>
              <span class="lsep">|</span>
              <a href="/posts/64535387/edit" class="edit-post js-gps-track" data-gps-track="post.click({ item: 6, priv: 17, post_type: 1 })" title="revise and improve this post">edit</a>
              <span class="lsep">|</span>
              <button id="btnFollowPost-64535387" class="s-btn s-btn__link fc-black-400 h:fc-black-700 pb2 js-follow-post js-follow-question js-gps-track" role="button" data-gps-track="post.click({ item: 14, priv: 17, post_type: 1 })" data-controller="s-tooltip " data-s-tooltip-placement="bottom" data-s-popover-placement="bottom" aria-controls="" aria-describedby="--stacks-s-tooltip-rlrg4nxp">
                follow
              </button><div id="--stacks-s-tooltip-rlrg4nxp" class="s-popover s-popover__tooltip pe-none" aria-hidden="true" role="tooltip">Follow this question to receive notifications<div class="s-popover--arrow"></div></div>
              <span class="lsep">|</span>
              <a href="#" class="close-question-link js-gps-track js-close-question-link" data-gps-track="post.click({ item: 9, priv: 17, post_type: 1 })" title="vote to close this question (when closed, no new answers can be added)" data-questionid="64535387" data-show-interstitial="" data-isclosed="false">close</a>
              <span class="lsep">|</span>
              <a href="#" class="flag-post-link js-gps-track" data-gps-track="post.click({ item: 5, priv: 17, post_type: 1 })" title="flag this post for serious problems or moderator attention" data-postid="64535387">flag</a>
              <span class="lsep">|</span>
              <div data-controller="s-popover" data-s-popover-reference-selector="#btnProtectLoggedIn">
                <button id="btnProtectLoggedIn" class="s-btn s-btn__link fc-black-400 h:fc-black-700 px4 pb2 js-gps-track" role="button" aria-controls="divConfirmProtect" data-gps-track="post.click({ item: 12, priv: 17, post_type: 1 })" data-action="s-popover#toggle" data-s-popover-placement="bottom-start" data-s-popover-toggle-class="is-selected" title="disallow answers by anonymous and very new low rep users">
                  protect
                </button>
                <div class="s-popover px16" id="divConfirmProtect" role="menu" aria-hidden="true">
                  <p class="bold mb4">Are you sure?</p>
                  <p class="mb12">Protect this question if it is highly active and likely to receive spam activity or non-answers (e.g. "Me too!" "Thanks!"). Anonymous and low reputation users can’t answer protected questions. <a href="/help/privileges/protect-questions">Learn more.</a></p>
                  <p class="mb0">
                    <button id="protect-post-64535387" class="s-btn s-btn__primary mr8" type="button" aria-pressed="false">Protect question</button>
                    <button class="s-btn s-btn__link" type="button" aria-pressed="false" aria-label="Close" data-action="s-popover#toggle">Cancel</button>
                  </p>
                  <div class="s-popover--arrow"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="post-signature owner grid--cell">
            <div class="user-info ">
              <div class="user-action-time">
                asked <span title="2020-10-26 10:31:30Z" class="relativetime">yesterday</span>
              </div>
              <div class="user-gravatar32">
                <a href="/users/13609752/yasin-demirkaya"><div class="gravatar-wrapper-32"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Ghue30DHLGWKxu5iK2LpyQskJVNNGvkiWGN2Wt6=k-s32" alt="" width="32" height="32" class="bar-sm"></div></a>
              </div>
              <div class="user-details" itemprop="author" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
                <a href="/users/13609752/yasin-demirkaya">Yasin Demirkaya</a><span class="d-none" itemprop="name">Yasin Demirkaya</span>
                <div class="-flair">
                  <span class="reputation-score" title="reputation score " dir="ltr">9</span><span title="2 bronze badges" aria-hidden="true"><span class="badge3"></span><span class="badgecount">2</span></span><span class="v-visible-sr">2 bronze badges</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-layout--right">
      <div id="comments-64535387" class="comments js-comments-container bt bc-black-075 mt12" data-post-id="64535387" data-min-length="15">
        <ul class="comments-list js-comments-list" data-remaining-comments-count="0" data-canpost="true" data-cansee="false" data-comments-unavailable="false" data-addlink-disabled="false">
        </ul>
        <div class="comment-form">
          <form id="add-comment-64535387" class="" data-placeholdertext="Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments."><div class="js-comment-form-layout d-flex fw-wrap jc-end mt8"><div class="w75 fl-grow1"><div class="js-comment-text-input-container"><textarea name="comment" class="s-textarea js-comment-text-input" rows="3" cols="68" placeholder="Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments."></textarea></div><span class="text-counter cool">enter at least 15 characters</span> <span class="form-error"></span></div><div class="d-flex fd-column jc-space-between pb4 mb16 ml8"><button type="submit" class="s-btn s-btn__primary">Add Comment</button><button type="button" class="js-edit-comment-cancel s-btn s-btn__link ta-left px2 mt4"></button><br><button type="button" class="js-comment-help-link s-btn s-btn__link ta-left px2">help</button></div></div></form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="comments-link-64535387" style="display: none;">
        <a class="js-add-link comments-link" title="Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments." href="#" role="button">add a comment</a>
        <span class="js-link-separator dno">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
        <a class="js-show-link comments-link dno" title="expand to show all comments on this post" href="#" onclick="" role="button"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
`
});
new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```css
#app {
  width: 600px;
}
html, body {
  min-width: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/stacks.css?v=3b16a418cc4c">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/primary.css?v=fdd4b4684691">
<div id="app">
  <your-question />
</div>
```

Is it Vue? Entirely.
Does it have any reactive data? Not yet.
How much did it take? A copy-paste, basically.

Obviously, it's more than just that. You'll also need to load the javascript and it can't be in the `<template>`. And you'll likely want to cut portions of your markup into separate components. But, for starters, all you need to do is present the markup and load your scripts. Everything should work as if it wasn't Vue rendering it.

To make it clearer: Vue can render anything and it doesn't care what it is. It can be an Angular app or a React app or even another Vue app.

A tool like the one you're looking for does not and cannot exist, because it wouldn't know what part of the existing markup should be transformed into a Vue component.
But, basically, each Vue app is one big component, which replaces the DOM element you mount it on.

In the above example this is all the app's markup:

```
<div id="app">
   <your-question />
</div>
```

And `<your-question>`, defined as a Vue component does the rendering, when you create a
`new Vue({ el: '#app '})`.

Also note that, once you create a big Vue component, most IDEs will allow you to select a portion of its template and generate a new Vue component from the selected markup, creating the new SFC for you, copying the template portion into the new file and replacing the removed markup with the new component's tag, also resolving necessary imports and any required methods/computed/data or props.

Answer (score -1):

Since the css file already included all the styles you need, just referencing it in the index.html if you created the project via vue-cli.

For instance, I have a css file named `app.css`.

1. Copied it to public folder, where the `index.html` locates here as well.

```
public/
  - index.html
  - app.css
```

2. Open `index.html`, reference as that in HTML. But use `<% BASE_URL %>` at the beginning.

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= BASE_URL %>app.css">
```

In your case, you don't have to write any css code in vue components. Maybe just copying and pasting the HTML code is working. If you hope to override the style within a specific component, use `<style scoped>` to avoid impacting global styles.